# OSGi - Registering a service from a different bundle

Tags: java, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I have recently started learning OSGi. While experimenting with Apache Aries and OSGi blueprint, I created the following set-up:
Bundle A :

```
public interface IMessageSender {
    String send(String message);
    String getServiceName();
}

public interface IMessageSenderFactory {
    String name();
    IMessageSender create();
}
```

Bundle B (SMSSenderFactory is exported as a service):

```
public class SMSSender implements IMessageSender {

    public String send(String message) {
        return "Sent by SMS : "+message;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return "SMS";
    }
}

public class SMSSenderFactory implements IMessageSenderFactory {

    public String name() {
        return "SMS";
    }

    public IMessageSender create() {
        return new SMSSender();
    }

}
```

Bundle C :

```
public class BundleManagerImpl implements BundleManager{

    BundleContext bundleContext;

    Map<IMessageSenderFactory, List<ServiceRegistration>> senders = new HashMap<IMessageSenderFactory, List<ServiceRegistration>>();


    public void setBundleContext(BundleContext bundleContext) {
        this.bundleContext = bundleContext;
    }
    //reference listener method
    public void addSenderFactory(IMessageSenderFactory senderFactory) {
        this.senders.put(senderFactory, new ArrayList<ServiceRegistration>());
    }
    //reference listener method
    public void removeSenderFactory(IMessageSenderFactory senderFactory){
        List<ServiceRegistration> registeredSenders = this.senders.get(senderFactory);
        if (registeredSenders != null){
            for (ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration : registeredSenders) {
                serviceRegistration.unregister();
            }
        }
        this.senders.remove(senderFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> listFactories(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (IMessageSenderFactory senderFactory : senders.keySet()) {
            list.add(senderFactory.name());
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void createSenderServiceInstance(String type){
        IMessageSender sender = null;
        for (IMessageSenderFactory senderFactory : senders.keySet()) {
            if (senderFactory.name().equals(type)){
                sender = senderFactory.create();
                ServiceRegistration registration = bundleContext.registerService(IMessageSender.class.getName(), sender, null);
                this.senders.get(senderFactory).add(registration);
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

Bundle D:

```
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

    List<IMessageSender> senders = new ArrayList<IMessageSender>();
    //reference listener method
    public void addSender(IMessageSender sender) {
        this.senders.add(sender);
    }
    //reference listener method
    public void removeSender(IMessageSender sender){
        this.senders.remove(sender);
    }

    public List<String> send(String message) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (IMessageSender sender : this.senders) {
            String response = sender.send(message);
            list.add(MessageFormat.format("Sent by : {0}; Response : {1}", sender.getServiceName(), response));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

The goal was to allow creation of multiple, variable number of instances of the SMSSender service.
So my questions are:

1 - Is there anything wrong with this approach? I am creating an SMSSender instance, in bundle B and registering it as a service in Bundle C. Would this lead to any issues or does it violate any rule of OSGi?

2 - Are there any other approaches to reaching the same goal?

EDIT:

Bundle E (added later, exports EmailSenderFactory as service)

```
public class EmailSender implements IMessageSender {

    public String send(String message) {
        return "Sent by Email : "+message;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return "Email";
    }
}

public class EmailSenderFactory implements IMessageSenderFactory {

    public String name() {
        return "Email";
    }

    public IMessageSender create() {
        return new EmailSender();
    }

}
```

Comment: Unless you've got a specific reason for keeping bundles B and C separate I'd combine those. Implementing and registering the service seems like functionality that goes together to me.

Comment: The reason for doing so would be, I could later add a bundle E with something like `EmailSender` and `EmailSenderFactory`. And yes, I also felt those functionalities should go together, which is why I was wondering if this code actually violated some design rule.

Comment: That's covered by having the interfaces separated into bundle A, which looks like the right approach. Can't see any problems with the way you've set it up. Not sure there are any rules to break, but it's a good idea to keep closely related functionality together and minimise dependencies and interfaces between bundles.

Comment: Added a bundle E to the example, which is why I was keeping B and C separate. Also @NickWilson how would you design a system, where you could have multiple, and variable number of the same service?